# finite almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

I have a sequence $(q_n)_{n \geq \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and I wish to 
show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} 1_{[q_n,q_n+1/n]} < \infty$ $\lambda$ almost everywhere, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.  I can see intuitively why it must be true, but I have little idea about how to begin the proof.

Comment: **Hint:** Integrate.

Comment: i know that the integral gives $\pi^2/6$ that i have already calculated when you integrate over the whole space. But does that give me the answer?

Comment: If a (nonnegative) function has finite integral, what is the measure of the set where it attains the value $+\infty$?